# Why won't my <UL> expand to wrap the <LI> elements it contains?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, html-lists

I'm using WordPress. I have a menu that is built with a list.

Basically, its sample is like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>FrontPage</li>
    <li>MenuItem</li>
    <li>ParentMenuItem
        <ul> <--- This wont adjust its height to fit its children
            <li>MenuItemChild</li>
            <li>MenuItemChild</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>MenuItem</li>
</ul>
```

Now the ParentMenuItem won't expand and cover all its children with its background and border. I cant figure out why. Only way I have been able to make it cover is by giving it a fixed height.

Comment: Can you create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to repro your issue?

Comment: Thanks for replying Maverick but Zhihao already solved my problem

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change the `height` of your `ul` from `100%` to `auto`:

```
height: auto;
```

The reason your `ul` height is too small is because you are using `100%`, which means it will take on the height of its parent. It does *not* mean to take up the maximum space available, nor does it mean to take on the sum of the height of all its children. Since the parent has `height: 33px`, your `ul` also has that height.

Comment: @AronChan if this answer solved your issue, you can mark it as the answer by clicking on the checkmark to the left of this post. This way, others who have the same problem will be able to recognize the solution.

Comment: Yea.. i had to wait a few minutes before being allowed to answer :)

Answer (score 1):

In this rule

```
.menu-primary-container ul li ul {
    height: 100%;
    /* ... */
}
```

you must remove `height`.

And you must rename the selector

```
.menu-primary-container ul
```

to

```
.menu-primary-container > ul
```

in order to affect only first `ul`, not all descendants.

Comment: I haven't checked this myself, but it sounds like this would be a better solution than the one I suggested. If your styling is being applied to all descendants when you just want the children, I would prefer changing the selector rather than overwriting the lower levels with the correct style.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your `<li>`'s are floated left, which means they don't give any form to the containing element.

If you set the nested `<li>` to `float: none; clear: both;` it should fix the problem.